# Структура проекта django с постоянно работающим воркером

Tags: python, django, celery

Мне нужен совет по структуре проекта.

У меня есть скрипт-воркер, который постоянно держит коннект со SteamAPI под логином и паролем для того, чтобы получать данные о пользователях и заполнять ими html.

Мне интересны ответы на любой из следующих вопросов, буду очень благодарен.

1. Где расположить скрипт по отношению к папке с сеттингами
2. С помощью чего запустить скрипт, чтобы он работал постоянно, и из него можно было получать ответы на запросы (как я предполагаю, через Celery, но как запустить процесс, чтобы он не прекращался, запустился вместе с сайтом и возвращал данные?)

Comment: 1) management-команда; 2) management-команда

Comment: посмотрел что такое manegment команды и немного не понял что вы имеете ввиду.